# Django, unobtrusive JavaScript and cross-site scripting

Tags: python, ajax, django

am wondering if there is a manual/tutorial that talks about advance use of JavaScripting and django, using existing frameworks such as JQuery or Prototype, generating unobtrusive JavaScripting with no inline Javascripting.

Another question, is there a place where I can read about cross-site scripting and how I can protect my django project from such a thing?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Security section of The Django Book](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter20/) will get you started.